# pH indicator that will fluoresce under UV light

Tags: ph

I'm interested in a pH indicator that will strongly fluoresce under a typical black light that anyone could buy.  I want to use an acid base reaction to get an idea of how fast two liquids mix in a new type of mixing device.  Therefore the pH indicator has to have a very rapid reaction rate with either acid or base so that mixing is the rate limiting step.

I remember someone using coumaric acid decades ago for something similar. He showed me some beautiful photographs of how the fluorescence went from bright green to colorless when the pH went from basic to acidic. However, I don't remember the particular isotope and can no longer contact this person.  In my planned tests, I was thinking of using a 20% excess of either acid or base (depending upon the chosen indicator) so that after the liquids mixed and reacted, the resulting solution would be either strongly basic or strongly acidic.  Of course this depends on the indicator.  But something like the coumaric acid idea would work well in my case where I want to take photographs.  Ideally, I would like the chosen indicator to be environmentally safe.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=14&ved=2ahUKEwiEn-L4k83oAhVPOs0KHfYNAkkQFjANegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2Fpmc%2Farticles%2FPMC3647017%2F&usg=AOvVaw3oEkDke0eV-pwd9dneB3LR

Comment: E.g., https://www.thermofisher.com/de/de/home/references/molecular-probes-the-handbook/ph-indicators/overview-of-ph-indicators.html mentions some of these as suitable for a determination in living cells.

Comment: I've collected fluorescent rocks. Typical lighting washes out any fluorescence so you really need to look at UV fluorescence in the dark. Also glass doesn't transmit UV well. // How about adding a strong base, say NaOH, to an acidic solution with phenolphthalein? The indicator goes from colorless to pink.

Comment: @MaxW Agreed, behind the (normal glass) window is no sun burn. The OP could mount the UV lamp from the TLC box over the beaker containing solution A and receiving reagent solution B to bypass this limit.  Yet equally there is fluorescence microscopy with samples dyed (e.g., to mark nucleic acids) with stains sometimes excited by UV, too (e.g., DAPI, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAPI).

Comment: Going the other way, you could use quinine (from ordinary tonic water or more concentrated solution) as the [fluorophore](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/130758/79678) and quench the fluorescence with chloride ion (from ordinary salt water). For the light source, use a blacklight or [405 nm BluRay laser diode](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/130935/79678) or UV LED, etc.

Comment: Possibly this answer would help you: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/111455/61578

Comment: @EdV: BODIPY dyes are very expensive so won't fit into OP's budget. :-)

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Ah, your linked answer is your usual excellence! I have bookmarked it for the next time! As for the BODIPY, that link was what popped up in a quick search of “fluorescent pH indicators”. Personally, I would try the salt water and tonic water: safe, inexpensive, and no nasty dye mess if a leak happens. I had a CHEE colleague who studied fluid mixing, using ethylene glycol and rhodamine 6G laser dye. Cool under blacklight illumination, but it attracted lots of ants and dye ended up all over.

Comment: @EdV:  The salt water and tonic water idea sounds interesting.  However, I haven't been able to find a reference indicating how fast the quenching reaction is.  The only thing I saw was a paper where the assumption was made that the reaction was fast enough to result in a diffusion-limited process.  My mixer will mix two low-viscosity liquids in a few milliseconds or less.  So, do you know how large the reaction rate constant is? Also, the concentration of quinine in tonic water is only 82 ppm.  This will result in very low concentrations reducing the reaction rate below what might be expected

Comment: My gut feeling is that quenching will occur in under a millisecond. The quinine concentration can be increased a great deal by starting with quinine sulfate and making higher concentration solutions in 0.05 M sulfuric acid. As well, the higher the salt concentration, the better. In any event, the problem is basically the same for mixing a pH dependent fluorescent dye and acid or base. High concentrations are good!

Comment: @EdV:  My calculatons show that 82 ppm of quinine is a molar concentration of about .000253 moles/liter.  That's about 50 to 100 times lower than the concentrations I was thinking about using for an acid-base reaction using an indicator. The solubility of quinine sulfate in water is 2mg/mL or by comparison 2000 ppm.  I've seen some tonic water syrups available.  I wonder if I couldn't mix higher concentrations using syrup and water.  My understanding is that the 82 ppm amount is health imposed limitation.

Comment: Yeah, the 82 ppm is a health imposed limit. You can definitely use the syrups and I just checked ebay: quinine sulfate powder is available. It costs about 4 dollars per gram.

Comment: I'm looking for "black light" LED units on amazon.  Looks like wavelengths are 395 to 400 nm.  One manufacturer says to choose a slightly lower wavelength for better fluorescense (around 375 to 390 nm).  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The wavelength range you give would be somewhat better, but not by much, and the 395 to 400 nm LEDs are inexpensive, so you can run a dozen. The peak absorbance wavelength is 350 nm, but there is no reason to pay more for LEDs with that nominal wavelength. And without a spectrometer, you cannot easily tell if you are getting what you paid for. Sorry I did not see your comment before now!

Comment: It looks like I can't buy quinine sulfate since I don't have an established commercial address.  Can anyone suggest other fluorescent indicators that I could buy as an individual or another way to get quinine (maybe from a concentrated syrup or something similar).